# How to populate a gridview from Active Directory in Visual C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, ldap

I'm currently using Visual C# with ASP.NET framework, and I am trying to populate a GridView via a `DataTable`. The information is being obtained from Active Directory.

My gridview is being declared like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="567px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my code to attempt to fill the gridview is the following:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP"]);

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
        {
            SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
            Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Dartmouth))"
        };

search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");

SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();

DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;

//Add columns to DataTable
table.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
table.Columns.Add("Phone", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
table.Columns.Add("Email", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

foreach (SearchResult sr in uList)
{
    dr = table.NewRow();

    DirectoryEntry DE = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    dr["Name"] = DE.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
    dr["Phone"] = DE.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
    dr["Email"] = DE.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();

    table.Rows.Add(dr);
}

table.AcceptChanges();

grdvList.DataSource = table;
grdvList.DataBind();
```

Currently when I run it, it throws an

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

at this line:

```
dr["Phone"] = DE.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
```

Any help is definitely appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you could avoid using **DataTable** and **DataSet** which are old technology. These days, we try not to use them, unless we do not have any other choice.

For ***NullReferenceException***, you want to make sure `DE.Properties["mail"]` is not null before getting its `Value`.

For example,

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP"]);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
{
    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Dartmouth))"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();

var users = result.Cast<SearchResult>().Select(sr => sr.GetDirectoryEntry())
    .Select(de => new 
    {
        Name = de.Properties["Name"] != null ? de.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString() : "",
        Phone = de.Properties["Phone"] != null ? de.Properties["Phone"].Value.ToString() : "",
        Email = de.Properties["Email"] != null ? de.Properties["Email"].Value.ToString() : "",
    }).ToList();

grdvList.DataSource = users;
grdvList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Okay, this is a step in the right direction. Only error in your code is that we need `Name = de.Properties["Name"].Value != null` instead of `Name = de.Properties["Name"] != null`.

My gridview is filled with the appropriate amount of rows, however there is nothing in them... http://i.imgur.com/eVaodTy.png

Comment: You still need **datafield** attribute for boundfield. For example, `<asp:boundfield datafield="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True""/>`

Comment: That worked! The only remaining issue was that in the original code you posted, you didn't use the correct LDAP names. de.properties["mail"] for instance. It now works though, thank you!